# Posting 2 Values on one mysql_query drop down

Tags: php, mysql, database

DB MAP:

```
Carriers "table1": carriername, carrierid, ect... Post data
carrierinfo "table2": carriername, id, contact, ect... carrier list
```

I am using `mysql_query` from `table2` for my `carriername` drop down. Using this I am able to post a carrier name to `table1`. I am trying to use the same drop down to post the related `id` from the selcected `carriername`. So in short I need to have one drop down that displays only the Carrier names but querys both  `carriername` & `id` from table2. When the form is posted I need to post to the `carriername` & `carrierid` to table1. Below is the drop down I am using. Please let me know how I can connect the dots and add what is needed. If its possible.

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "Submit")
{
    for ($count = 1; $count <= 9; $count++)
    {
        $fields[$count] = "";
        if (isset($_POST["field" . $count . ""]))
        {
            $fields[$count] = trim($_POST["field" . $count . ""]);
            //echo $fields[$count] . "<br />";
        }
    }

    $con = mysql_connect("", "", "");
    mysql_select_db("", $con);

    $carrierid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['carrierid']);
    $fromzip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fromzip']);
    $tozip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tozip']);
    $typeofequipment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['typeofequipment']);
    $weight = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weight']);
    $length = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['length']);
    $paymentamount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['paymentamount']);
    $contactperson = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactperson']);
    $loadtype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loadtype']);
    $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO Carriers (`carriername` ,`carrierid`, `fromzip` ,`tozip` ,`typeofequipment` ,`weight` ,`length` ,`paymentamount` ,`contactperson` ,`loadtype` ,`date`) 
    SELECT carriername ,'$carrierid' ,'$fromzip' ,'$tozip' ,'$typeofequipment' ,'$weight' ,'$length' ,'$paymentamount' ,'$contactperson' ,'$loadtype', NOW()) FROM carrierinfo WHERE id = '$carrierid'";

    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

    $select = "SELECT `carriername` ,`fromzip` ,`tozip` ,`typeofequipment` ,`weight` ,`length` ,`paymentamount` ,`contactperson` ,`loadtype` FROM `Carriers` ORDER BY `date` DESC;";
    $result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());

}
?>
<style ="text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='search.php';" value="Search Board" /><div
 style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 16px 20px 20px; width: 400px; background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216); text-align: center; float: left;">
<form action="" method="post";">
  <div
  style="margin: 8px auto auto; width: 300px; font-family: arial; text-align: left;"><br>
  <table style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
   <table
 style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 10%;">Carrier:</td><td>
 <?php  

$con = mysql_connect("", "", "");
    mysql_select_db("", $con);

$query=("SELECT * FROM carrierinfo"); 

$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Unable to Make the Query:" . mysql_error() ); 
echo "<select name='carrierid'>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
echo "<OPTION VALUE='".$row['id']."'>".$row['carriername']."</OPTION>";
}
echo "</select>"; 

?>
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 10%;">Load Type:</td><td>
              <select name="loadtype">
              <option></option>
              <option value="TL">Truck Load</option>
              <option value="Partial">Partial</option>
              </select>
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Pick Zip:</td><td> <input id="fromzip" name="fromzip" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Drop Zip:</td><td> <input id="tozip" name="tozip" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Weight:</td><td> <input id="weight" name="weight" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Length:</td><td> <input id="length" name="length" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="width: 10%;">Equip:</td><td>
              <select name="typeofequipment">
              <option></option>
              <option value="AUTO">Auto Carrier</option>
              <option value="DD">Double Drop</option>
              <option value="F">Flatbed</option>
              <option value="LB">Lowboy</option>
              <option value="Rail">Rail</option>
              <option value="Ref">Reefer</option>
              <option value="RGN">Removable Goose Neck</option>
              <option value="SD">Step Deck</option>
              <option value="TANK">Tanker (Food, liquid, etc.)</option>
              <option value="V">Van</option>
              </select>
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Contact:</td><td> <input id="contactperson" name="contactperson" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Rate:</td><td> <input id="paymentamount" name="paymentamount" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
          </tbody>
  </table>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><input name="submit" value="Submit"
 class="submit" type="submit"><input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='newcarrier.php';" value="Add Carrier" /></p>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: -20px;">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you know what a "join" is? This is basic SQL stuff.

Comment: no please explain. I am new to writing. If you could show me an example that would be great. Otherwise I could look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT t1.carrierid, t2.carriername, t2.id
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 USING (carriername)
```

Joining tables should be one of the first things you learn when studying SQL.

UPDATE:

Never mind the above, your original query to populate the dropdown was correct. When you populate the select, you should do:

```
echo "<select name='carrierid'>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
  echo "<OPTION VALUE='".$row['id']."'>".$row['carriername']."</OPTION>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

When posting the data, get rid of this line:

```
$carriername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['carriername']);
```

and change the insert query to:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO Loads (`carriername` ,`carrierid`, `fromzip` ,`tozip` ,`typeofequipment` ,`weight` ,`length` ,`paymentamount` ,`contactperson` ,`loadtype` ,`date`) 
  SELECT carriername ,'$carrierid' ,'$fromzip' ,'$tozip' ,'$typeofequipment' ,'$weight' ,'$length' ,'$paymentamount' ,'$contactperson' ,'$loadtype', NOW())
  FROM Carriers
  WHERE id = '$carrierid'";
```

The change to the form makes it display the carrier name, but return the ID in the post data.  Then the new INSERT query uses that ID to get the carrier name from table 2 and combine that with all the other post data when inserting into table 1.

Comment: Its the firts time I personally have come accoss it. I know..I'm a noob.

Comment: I added it and it seems like the drop down is reading all the 'carriername' data from table 1. see the code above. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want then. This query just gets the related data from table 1 and table 2, using the carriername columns to link them. I don't know what you mean by "post a carrier name to table 1", since your script doesn't update anything.

Comment: I'll show you my entire page to show. As of now the dropdown is reading the carriernames from table1. I need it to be from the list in table2. See the code.

Comment: Because of the join, the carriernames should be the same. It sounds like you need to explain better how these two tables are related to each other, I assumed carriername was the link between them because you gave the columns the same name.

Comment: Ok.. so what I want to link is the id. At the same time only display the list of carriers in table2.

Comment: table1 is where all the inserts get put. table2 is just the list of carriers that I want to call apon.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you want. The dropdown just has carrier names, but you want to insert carrierid in the table, but there's no `$_POST['carrierid']`. Give me a few minutes to update my answer.

Comment: See the updated answer now, I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Im getting this when I submit: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM carrierinfo WHERE id = '3'' at line 2